# WooCommerce Allow Backorders For Specific Categories When "Manage Stock" Is Unchecked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I'm currently using the WooCommerce Attribute Stock plugin to allow for the sharing of stock between products/variations.

I want to allow Backorders for products in specific categories, with specific attributes. Unfortunately, I can't just use "Manage Stock" at the product level as this overrides the Attribute Stock.

I've tried the following snippet but it doesn't seem to work. The category check is breaking the ability to allow the product to be backordered. It shows the backorder stock message but when you actually try to add the product to the cart it triggers a notice of "You cannot add ""ABC"" to the cart because the product is out of stock.":

```
function __enable_backorders($value, $product) {

    //Set the product categories in the array
    $categories = array('cat-a', 'cat-b');

    // Allow Backorder For All Products In Specific Categories WITH Specific Attribute
    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) && $product->get_attribute('pa_attr-a') ){
    
        // Enables Manage Stock - Use "yes" or "notify"
        return $product->get_manage_stock('edit') ? $value : 'notify';

    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_backorders', '__enable_backorders', 0, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_backorders', '__enable_backorders', 0, 2);
```

The above snippet seems to work properly if I remove the category condition and just have the attribute condition; which isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

What would be the best way to also include a condition to check for specific attributes in addition to specific array of categories?

Ideally from there I'd also like to customize the "x in stock (can be backordered)" and "Available on backorder" message for specific attributes as well (i.e *if* Category is A *and* Product has X attribute then display custom message).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My question was a bit of a 2-parter, I think I've worked out both, so thought I'd share for anyone trying to do the same.

This might not be most optimized code so if anyone has any corrections please feel post them. :)

**Part 1: Allow Backorders When "Manage Stock" Is Unchecked For Specific Categories/Attribute - Credit to Ovidiu from WPCodeBox**

```
/**
 * @snippet       Allow Backorders When "Manage Stock" Is Unchecked For Specific Categories/Attribute - Credit to Ovidiu from WPCodeBox @ WooCommerce Single Product Page
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 5.6
 */

function __enable_backorders( $value, $product ) {

    //Set the product categories in the array
    $categories = array('cat-a');

    // Product variations are not assigned to categories, if it is a variation, get the post ID of the parent
    $product_post = get_post($product->id);

    // If it is a variation
    if($product_post->post_parent) {
        $product_id = $product_post->post_parent;
    } else {
        $product_id = $product->id;
    }

    // Allow Backorder For All Products In Specific Categories WITH Specific Attribute
   if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $product->get_attribute('pa_attr-a') ){

    // Enables Manage Stock - Use "yes" or "notify"
    return $product->get_manage_stock('edit') ? $value : 'notify';

   }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_backorders', '__enable_backorders', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_backorders', '__enable_backorders', 10, 2);
```

**Part 2: Change Stock Availability Message Per Category/Attribute**

```
/**
 * @snippet       Change Stock Availability Message Per Category/Attribute @ WooCommerce Single Product Page
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 5.6
 */

function filter_product_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {

    //Set the product categories in the array
    $categories = array('cat-a', 'cat-b');
    
    // In Stock, Can Be Backordered  - Has Specific Categories/Attributes
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount' ) && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) && $product->get_attribute('pa_attr-a') ) {

        $availability = str_replace('in stock (can be backordered)', 'Available', $availability);

    } else {

        // Out of stock, Backorders Allowed - Has Specific Categories/Attributes
        if ( $product->backorders_allowed() && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) && $product->get_attribute('pa_attr-a') ) {

            $availability = str_replace('Available on backorder', '<strong>Backordered</strong><span class="bo-message">My custom message goes here.</span>', $availability);

        } elseif ( $product->backorders_allowed() && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) && $product->get_attribute('pa_attr-b') ) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }

    }

    return $availability;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
```